# Vertical Nav Menu with submeu that expands

Tags: html, css, menu, nav, expand

I am trying to create something like this http://www.thomascheng.com/portfolio.php#

But I'm not sure what it is called in order to search for it. What I am interested in is how the submenus expand out when you click the main link, and then when you click a submenu item, the right side slides to that area of the page. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: That is an Accordion.  http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an Accordion.  Check out jQuery's version here: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 0):

Its accordion. You might also find this worthwhile:

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navs